# ZK Tree, How to get treemodel from tree to make the transaction on backend

Tags: tree, zk

I am working on zk tree, When I made some changes dynamically on the Tree, I need to get the updated model associated with the tree to see what are the updated/delete items and also how to iterated a treemodel, so that I can made proper transactions on the backend. 
For the time being not able to get the model and list of objects from that model for this purpose.

Looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Tree`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Tree.html) component has a method [`getModel()`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Tree.html#getModel%28%29). If you need
a complete list and do not have your onw `TreeModel`, you have
to do [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). But, [`TreeModel`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/TreeModel.html) provides `DataListners`
that may solve at least some of your problems without the need of a complete list.
[`TreeDataListner`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/event/TreeDataListener.html) has the method `onChange(TreeDataEvent event)` 
where `event.getType()` denotes the type of action ([see static fields](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/event/TreeDataEvent.html)).
If you want to implement your onw `Model`, have a look at [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/Performance%20Tips/Listbox,%20Grid%20and%20Tree%20for%20Huge%20Data/Implement%20ListModel%20and%20TreeModel).

Comment: Thank you Nabil, i got the tree.getModel, but how can i iterate over it? i want to put back the values in same order in Database.

Comment: See the link tree traversal. It links a Wikipedia article about iterating trough a tree. At `Example` you see the order of the different algorithms.